# Java object oriented programming and polymorphism

Tags: java, object, polymorphism

Suppose there are 20 subclasses derived from the main class. Suppose each class also has its own properties. Let's say we have a manager class; it takes the main class as a parameter and adds a database. We can give the parameter as polymorphic, yes, but when adding a database, its own, special features cannot be accessed with polymorphism. Since there are 20 pieces, it does not make much sense to use instance of separately in if. What can be done?

```java
public class Person {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Student extends Person {

    private int studentNo;

    public int getStudentNo() {
        return studentNo;
    }

    public void setStudentNo(int studentNo) {
        this.studentNo = studentNo;
    }
}
```

```java
public class PersonManager {

    public void add(Person person) {
        System.out.println("saved: " + person.getName());
        System.out.println("saved: " + person.getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, I wrote the code wrong, corrected it. However, I still haven't found a solution for the problem I mentioned.

Comment: If you're targeting something like a SQL database, then I would look into using a library that does this for you. For instance, you could use a full-blown Object Relational Mapper (ORM) like Hibernate. If you're looking to save objects to a file or send them over a network, then I would look into serialization libraries, such as Jackson which is capable of converting to and from e.g., JSON format.

Comment: I am working to be a backend developer. After completing the object oriented programming topics, I will start working with spring boot or hibernate.

Comment: For an interface to exist it must be or become part of a loaded "class instance" , however, when a class is also another class type (extended from) and much similar , with an I terrace then there is more than one type the class instance is. That for basics is polymorphism in java. E.g. a java.awt.Canvas is also a javax.accessibility.Accessible and also a java.awt.Component . A more practical way of adding a type is casting an abstract class onto a class instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a `Person.add_database` method, and override it on each subclass. Now you keep the fields encapsulated, at the cost of a little bit of boilerplate when creating subclasses.

```java
public class Person {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    ...

    public void addDatabase(Datatabase db) {
        // Process the Person-specific fields.
        System.out.println("saved: " + this.getName());
        System.out.println("saved: " + thisgetId());
    }
}

public class Student extends Person {

    private int studentNo;

    ...

    @Override
    public void addDatabase(Database db) {
        // Handle the Person fields.
        super.addDatabase(db);
        // Handle the fields unique to Student.
        System.out.println("saved: " + this.getStudentNo());
    }
}

public class PersonManager {

    public void add(Person person, Database db) {
        // We don't care about the type of Person, they'll handle themselves.
        person.addDatabase(db);
        // Prints id, name, *and* studentNo if given a student.
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can use [@annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/basics.html) to mark the fields to be processed, or [reflection](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html) to inspect all fields.

However, those solutions are more "magic". I personally find they create hard-to-debug issues, but some communities are big fans.

Answer (score 3):

The answer from @BoppreH answers your question, but I think you are heading down a rabbit hole with your class hierarchy. The assumption that a Person is a Manager is fine at any instant in time, but once you bring a database into the picture, the model deteriorates as time becomes a factor. For instance you may be a student today, an Employee next year and a Manager at some time in the future. To do this, we usually use composition rather than inheritance.

The best approach is to model roles in the real world - a Person is a Student for a defined period of time, an Employee for a later period and a Manager even later. The usual way to do this is to have three database tables:

1. Person, which holds data about the actual person. e.g. Name, date of birth, gender.
2. Role, which contains one record per possible role - e.g. Title, financial authority
3. PersonRole, which contains the records that define what role the person has. This table will have foreign keys to Person and Role, plus a startDate and endDate field.

An advantage of this structure is that you can add new roles by simple data entry.

Also, I would avoid putting the persistence logic in the classes. This means any time you use your classes, you need to have a database available. In a small system this is not a problem, but it is common for basic classes to be packaged into a library and used by many applications. Also, if using Java, database connections are not serializable, and this will one day come back to haunt you. The Repository pattern solves this neatly, and Google will show you how.

Best of luck with your project

Comment: And indeed ... a person can be an employee and a student *at the same time*.  It happens in the real world.  And I've seen real world university "user identity" systems *that are not able to cope with this in a sane way*.